# How to kill process in bash?

Tags: bash, process, kill

I used the following bash code:

```
for pid in `top -n 1 | awk '{if($8 == "R") print $1;}'`
do
  kill $pid
done
```

It says:

```
./kill.sh: line 3: kill: 29162: arguments must be process or job IDs
./kill.sh: line 3: kill: 29165: arguments must be process or job IDs
./kill.sh: line 3: kill: 29166: arguments must be process or job IDs
./kill.sh: line 3: kill: 29169: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

Any ideas? Thank you!